# How to store an Encrypted type in flutter sharedprefrence

Tags: flutter, encryption, sharedpreferences

Am designing an app in flutter and I have successfully encrypted a string using [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt). now i want to store this encrypted data in sharedpreference so i can retrieve it later and decrypt it before using. I have tried setString() it does not work as it seem 'Encrypted' is a type itself so won't work with strings. Is there any work around.

this is my code

```
Encrypted runEncrypt( String caption) {
    final key = Key.fromUtf8('u^Hrf64hFrM08HuytDeMK7654DgJlP');
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

    final encryptPro = Encrypter(AES(key));

    final encrypted = encryptPro.encrypt(caption, iv: iv);

    return encrypted;
  }

/////
Encrypted keyz=runEncrypt('this is the key');
pref.setString("key",keyz);
```

Comment: Could you share a code example so we can test it to find a solution.

Comment: @TesteurManiak i have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `base64` property of your encrypted object it returns a `String`.
In the [source code of the package](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/blob/master/lib/src/encrypted.dart#L40) it says that it returns the `Encrypted` as a Base64 String representation.

```
pref.setString("key", keyz.base64);
```

use the same encoding while decrypting

```
Encrypter.decrypt64(valueFromSharedPref)
```